# Check submitted form against database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Working on creating a question based website using Ruby on rails,  still in planning so don't have much code to show,  just looking how it will logically work, we have a table of questions and answers,  where the answers table has a foreign key to the question,  so each answer belongs to one question.

How would one approach solving the problem of taking a users input from a submitted form,  checking the question if against the answers table and then checking if a the submitted form is correct or not to the answers table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest completing a rails tutorial or book first. So that you have better understanding of forms, controllers, models and database.

Comment: Hi Sergio,  thank you for the comment,  I have looked at it,  and I know and understand how to insert,  it's more about comparing the submitted answer to the one in the answers table that belongs to the specific question.

Comment: So you have the question and its answers. Also you have a submitted answer. You can just load the existing answers and check if submitted answer is similar/equal to one of them, using whatever logic you choose. I don't really see what the question is. You don't know how to load question's answers? Or how to find one item in an array? Or what?

Comment: That method seems like its not the best solution,  load all the answers,  there will be hundreds of answers, would much rather have some query that pulls the selected answer for the question?  And then compares them both

Comment: sure, query is also an option.

Comment: it seems that you're trying to come up with a perfect design from the start. This never works. :) Start writing the app. You know some of rails/activerecord, so you can get started. Eventually you'll get stuck, but then you can ask a much more focused answer. Which is more likely to be answerable.

Comment: I know, I normally would take this approach,  but I'm trying to get an understanding about how to approach this before I dive into the code,  hoping that it will make the development of the project faster,  easier and less of a mess :)  thank you for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126767/discussion-between-syn-and-sergio-tulentsev).